# Ambiguous method call issue in Scala

Tags: scala, overloading, traits

I have a trait, say A, which has a method:

```
def add(str:String): Unit
```

Trait B extends A,and have a method like:

```
def add(line: CharSequence): Unit
```

I write trait C:

```
trait C extends B with A
```

In trait C, if I make a call to method 'add' with a string argument, it gives me ambiguous method call issue,as there are overloaded versions of 'add' available.

Is there a workaround for this without modifying traits relationship here?

Comment: Can you change the method signature of `A.add` to take a `CharSequence` instead of a `String`?

Comment: No, I can't. A is from a library.

Comment: You don’t need to do this trait C extends B with A is fine as B extends A already. And just override the method add trait C